# Почему нет запятой в предложении с одиночным деепричастием?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастия

Почему нет запятой в предложении с одиночным деепричастием?

"Дрозд расправил крылья, потом(,) не торопясь(,) сложил голову".

Не вижу здесь значения образа действия, а вижу добавочное действие, к тому же стоит деепричастие не в конце предложения. Можно ли поставить запятые в данном случае?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

После двух ответов хотел сначала своё мнение выразить в комментариях, но получается слишком *многабукф*.

Да, позиция имеет значение. Да, чаще обособление встречается в начале и середине. Но в **пункте 7** рассматриваемого правила ([Деепричастные конструкции](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113), справочник Розенталя) сказано: "...одно и то же слово в начале или в середине предложения **может** обособляться, а в конце – нет". Никто не пишет "запрещено", "не допускается", "обязательно". Главное же, как ни банально, смысл, задумка, значение деепричастия, **целесообразность** его обособления/необособления.

Хотите выделить структурно, интонационно – выделяйте. Хотите показать глагольность, второстепенное действие – выделяйте. Но в данном случае я поддерживаю моих соответчиков и тоже не стал бы ставить запятые.

Вообще-то, оригинальное предложение, точнее, его перевод выглядит так (по крайней мере на сайте [ЛитЛайф](https://litlife.club/books/142210/read?page=24). «1984», Джордж Оруэлл):

> Метрах в пяти от них, почти на уровне их лиц, на ветку слетел дрозд. Может быть, он их не видел. Он был на солнце, они в тени. **Дрозд расправил крылья, потом не торопясь сложил, нагнул на секунду голову, словно поклонился солнцу, и запел.**

Здесь и так много запятых, прерываться ещё – совсем не кстати. Интонационный принцип в действии. Но это, как я думаю, не основная причина необособления.

Вот пример из того же пункта 7: *По дороге, **не торопясь,** они собирали грибы и ягоды.* Всё логично, всё красиво. Грамматика, интонация и семантика в симбиозе: *собирали* и при этом *не торопились*. Конечно, можно задать вопрос *"как?"*, только вот серединное положение деепричастия и, соответственно, интонация не позволяют не поставить запятые. В нашем же случае дополнительное действие как-то не очень просматривается: *сложил* и *не торопился* (?) – нет, не звучит; *складывал* и *не торопился* – может быть. Всё-таки **образ действия** (*каким образом?*) превалирует.

Обратите внимание на **6-й пункт** вышеупомянутого раздела справочника. Чтобы одиночное деепричастие обособлялось, сохраняло значение глагольности, к нему задаются вопросы: *когда, почему, вопреки чему* и пр., то есть "налицо или обстоятельство времени, или обстоятельство причины, или обстоятельство уступки, но только не обстоятельство образа действия..."

И в этом же пункте есть примеры с деепричастиями, приближающимися по значению к наречиям и указывающими на образ действия, которые располагаются в середине или в начале предложения:

*Он… **не считая** бросал деньги.*
*Иной простак **не шутя** так подумает.*
***Не умолкая** тот же крик тревожил слух.*
***Не торопясь** он прошёлся по комнате.*
***Не задумываясь** отвергла она.*

Ещё интересный момент в пользу необособления: "На обособление одиночного деепричастия может влиять его вид: деепричастия **несовершенного вида** (на -а/-я) чаще всего не обособляются, поскольку обычно они являются обстоятельством образа действия" (**пункт 8** того же раздела).

И вот ещё [предложения со словом *торопясь*](https://wordius.ru/%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8/%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%81%D1%8C/):

*Алхимик не торопясь слез с коня* (Алхимик — Пауло Коэльо).
*Когда лошадь достигла центра площади, всадник не торопясь спешился* (Мор, ученик Смерти — Терри Пратчетт).
*«Это ничего, хорошо, что ушла», — подумал Гарри и не торопясь потащил чемодан в спальню, приготовленную для тётушки Мардж* (Гарри Поттер и узник Азкабана — Джоан Роулинг).

Ну и на закуску (☺). В Викисловаре есть статья (правда, "голая"), где [**торопясь**](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%81%D1%8C) названо наречием.

Answer (score 3):

Наверно, потому, что здесь "не торопясь" = "неторопливо". Оно похоже на "не спеша", которое приравнивается к наречию. Хотя необособление "не торопясь" далеко не так удачно.

Позиция больше играет роль, когда добавочное действие становится обстоятельством: *вошла улыбаясь* (из примеров Розенталя). Улыбаться и входить — это же разные действия. Другое дело — входить (как?) не торопясь.

Comment: То есть смотрим, можно заменить на наречие или нет.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: *Дрозд расправил крЫлья, потом **не торопясь** сложил гОлову.*

Не видите здесь значения образа действия, а видите добавочное действие? А вы попробуйте заменить деепричастие **наречием "неторопливо"**, оно прекрасно впишется сюда.

А вот обособленное деепричастие с двумя паузами  вписывается плохо. Почему?  Это предложение явно состоит **из двух частей**, соответствующих **двум однородным сказуемым.**

Кроме того, обособленный в середине предложения оборот  **выделяет его**, особо подчеркивает, но здесь в этом нет необходимости.

И еще загляните в Нацкорпус, и вы увидите, что деепричастный оборот "не торопясь" **может обособляться или не обособляться** в предложениях разной структуры. Поэтому так важно при решении анализировать и учитывать грамматику.

[Нацкорпус](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&ct=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%81%D1%8C)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138478/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon--------).

Comment: Поступил ответ, вы правы, там о питании.

Answer (score 3):

**Комментарий на ответ**

Александр,  прочитала я ваш ответ, проголосовала за него и уже хотела написать «Отлично!», но призадумалась (как Ворона у Крылова). **Что-то показалось мне не так.**

1. Если сказать в общем, то это **эклектичность ответа**. Вы стараетесь изложить максимум информации, совместить все способы решения. И пожалуй, эта фраза меня не очень порадовала: «*Хотите выделить структурно, интонационно – выделяйте. Хотите показать глагольность, второстепенное действие – выделяйте*».  А вопрос как раз и был о том: «Можно ли поставить запятые в данном случае?» **Итак, разрешение дано?))**
2. **А вот здесь я с вами не согласна.** Опытный писатель правильно решит этот вопрос интуитивно, по слуху; к тому же у него есть контекст. Ученик же должен «угадать» правильный ответ, да еще **в «усеченном» составителями предложении**. А если не угадал, то придется разбираться с комиссией, там и доказывать своё мнение (глагольность это  или обстоятельственное значение). Проблема?
3. Прав был, пожалуй, oleedd – **довольно сложная это тема**, если решать ее по правилам, а другого решения Розенталь не предлагает.  Простая же она для тех, кто умеет **анализировать структуру предложения** и использует интонационный метод анализа.  А кто умеет? Практически никто, если не учитывать исключения.
4. Розенталь разбирает эту тему **на простых предложениях** – образно говоря, учит нас плавать на мелководье. Вот и примеры на экзаменах должны быть такими же, но составители это не учитывают.

Да и там не все так просто. Вот, к примеру, предложение: ***По дороге, не торопясь, они собирали грибы и ягоды.***  Есть выбор? Мне кажется, что нет.
Давайте проверим  структуру предложения без обособления: *По дороге неторопливо // они собирали грибы и ягоды.* Что-то не так с этим предложением, а именно: **два обстоятельства не сочетаются** друг с другом, а мы должны сделать после них паузу (это чувствуется на слух). Так что  выбора нет, обособление **обязательно.**

5. **Что же делать школьникам?** Развивайте интуицию, если нет желания освоить структурный анализ. **Подстановка наречия** как проверка структуры на слух – вот неплохой метод.

Остальные мне кажутся немного «детскими»: собирали и (при этом) не торопились, сложил (крылья) и (при этом)не торопился. К тому же множество разного рода проверок (эклектичность) запутывает и не дает ясности и уверенности.

Ну а если есть желание **проверить уже имеющийся ответ,** то заходите на форум, чтобы услышать мнение участников. Ваша задача – не спорить с ними, а просто услышать их ответ и принять его к сведению.

6. **Всегда хорошо найти оригинал предложения**: *Дрозд **распрАвил** крылья, потом не торопясь **сложИл**, нагнул на секунду **гОлову**, словно поклонился солнцу, и **запЕл**.*  Красиво! Обратим внимание на то, что ударениями выделен однородный ряд сказуемых.

Также обратим внимание на то, что **распространенный** сравнительный оборот здесь **обособляется** – он идет **как вставка, второй план речи**. А вот одиночное деепричастие превращать в такую вставку не стоит (это уже будет перебор).

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon, – красиво!  Ну уж как написал (ночью интуиция вела)... В целом мой ответ построен на доказательстве того, что обособление не нужно и даже некорректно, избыточно, не комильфо.

Comment: И вам спасибо – за понимание, за прекрасное чувство языка, за открытость новым знаниям. Я же сейчас «думаю» вот о чем (хотя сознание у меня утреннее, не сумеречное): надо бы ввести  АДМИНИСТРАТИВНОЕ НАКАЗАНИЕ составителям тестов за искажение художественной классики: «Дрозд расправил крылья, потом не торопясь сложил голову».  Спать собрался? А можно так сказать – сложил голову? Может, спрятал голову под крыло?

Comment: Кто этих дроздов знает, как они голову  «складывают», быстро или медленно? Может, по какой-то причине он на этот раз не торопился, и автор  (почему-то) хочет это подчеркнуть)) Тут не комильфо само предложение с его странным смыслом и структурой, так классики не пишут.

Answer (score 1):

Это один из тех вопросов, ответ на который до конца не знает никто, как и, например, вопрос тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, вопрос обособления сравнительных оборотов и т.д. Всё это является следствием того, что недоумки-лингвисты не додумались за несколько поколений допилить имеющиеся справочники до какого-то хоть сколько-нибудь приемлемого уровня. На практике получается так: люди смотрят в справочник и видят там отвратительные формулировки про ‟образ действия” и полтора примера, потом они спрашивают у лингвистов, а те отвечают им свойственную лингвистам шизу, — в итоге человек либо всегда обособляет деепричастные обороты, либо опирается не некие полуаморфные инструкции и мы получаем отчасти хаотичную пунктуацию в этой теме в Нац. корпусе.

Я так интерпретирую это правило: Если есть деепричастие или деепричастный оборот несовершенного вида, то подлежащее либо выполняет два действия одновременно, либо одно действие характеризует другое. Например, в предложении: ‟Он шёл по улице, думая о будущем” — два одновременных действия, а в предложении: ‟Он шёл по улице прихрамывая” — прихрамывание характеризует способ того, как человек идёт; в предложении: ‟Он висел на турнике, глядя в даль” — два действия одновременно, а в предложении: ‟Он висел на турнике держась одной рукой” — то, как человек висит, характеризуется. Исходя из такой интерпретации, в предложении: ‟Дрозд расправил крылья, потом не торопясь сложил голову” — запятую не следует ставить, так как тут деепричастие обозначает характеристику действия.

Comment: Согласен насчёт лингвистов, хотя Розенталя понять можно, но допиливать некоторые темы надо. А что здесь? *Она шла улыбаясь. Она вошла не стуча.* Здесь нет чистой характеризации действия.

Comment: Да, Розенталя можно простить за всё, потому что певая работа подобная может содержать бескрайнее колличество проблем. Подобные работы и должны превращаться во что-то качественное, когда другие люди замечают недостатки таких работ и исправляют их, допиливают какие-то темы, понимают какие-то ошибки организации тем в целом и организации внутри тем.

Comment: Согласно моим инструкциям в этих предложениях нужна запятая.

Comment: Он не сам работал, а вместе с Былинским (как минимум). И недостатки они исправляли, даже спрашивали о них (цитирую: "Авторы заранее выражают свою благодарность за все критические замечания и пожелания, связанные с использованием пособия"), потом вышли две новые версии. А вот насчёт авторства следующей, которая используется в интернете, у меня сомнения. Там есть вещи, которые Розенталь без пояснений написать не мог. Но у Розенталя запятая в таких предложениях стоит. Значит, инструкции нужно расширить.

Comment: Можно взять пример из Розенталя: ‟Старик шёл прихрамывая на правую ногу”, а потом найти в Нац. корпусе авторитетные похожие примеры с запятой:  Он шел, прихрамывая, в гору.  [Л. Н. Толстой. Война и мир. Том четвертый (1867-1869)] Можно взять любой пример, а потом найти с запятой и без запятой в Нац. корпусе у авторитетных авторов.

Comment: У Толстого вклинивание в структуру. Пункт 7 у Розенталя.

Comment: Там написано про место по отношению глаголу-сказуемому. Там ничего конкретно не написано. Там написано, что если не в конце, то может и не обособляться. Классический говнопункт. В том же справочнике можно найти какой-нибудь такой пункт: Веретьев сидел наклонившись и похлопывал веткой по траве (Т.);

Comment: Или вот такой пример из справочника Розенталя: Шли обнявшись по лесной дороге. Он по структуре прямо один в один, как пример Толстого, но обособления нет.

Comment: Просто о чем этот 7-й пункт? О том, что есть обороты, которые стоят не в конце и обособляются? А есть те, которые стоят не в конце и обособляются, и что?

Comment: О том, что это имеет место быть. Розенталь не захотел это объяснять, думаю, что раз я понимаю, как это работает, то он тем более понимал. Ну вот у Толстого в середине, хотя думаю, что там и без запятых можно. Вот, пример про лесную дорогу в доказательство.